# How to unhide hidden objects with a Python script?

Tags: python

Here are a few objects that I have hidden:

[image]

I am using the script below to make them visible:

```
bpy.ops.object.hide_view_clear()
```

but it does not help.

So what is the perfect script to make them visible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of Blender 2.81, [`Object.hide_set()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=hide_viewport#bpy.types.Object.hide_set) is working properly and seems to be the equivalent of `Object.hide` property in 2.7x versions.

Proof using the console:

```
>>> bpy.context.object.hide_set(False)
```

To *unhide* multiple objects you can run over objects in the scene and call the *setter* per object:

```
for o in ("Cube", "Camera", "Light"):
   obj = bpy.context.scene.objects.get(o)
   #if obj: obj.hide_viewport = False
   if obj: obj.hide_set(False)
```

You can also iterate through any given collection:

```
col = bpy.data.collections.get("Collection")
if col:
   for obj in col.objects:
       obj.hide_set(False)
```

Whatever you like...

Comment: Is it possible to simulate the `Shift+Mouse_Click` for hiding an object with its children. Now I am iterating over the children objects and `hide_set(True)` them individually. My guess is that under the hood is the same procedure that is happening but I was wondering if someone can just call the build in functon instead of re-implementing it.

Comment: Hi! `Shift+LMB` is reserved for multi-selection in the outliner. I recommend ask a new detailed question referring to this one @ttsesm

Comment: I see, thanks. I will open a new thread.

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to specify which objects to unhide. Hidden objects cannot be selected, so you cannot just use `bpy.context.selected_objects`, you can use their names to identify them or whatever other attribute. You will need to loop through the objects from which you wish to pick the ones to unhide, you could use bpy.data.objects to do that for all scenes, but bpy.context.scene.objects are all the objects in the current scene that you are more likely to wish to work with. The script picking them by name could be something like this:

```
import bpy

for o in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if 'Cube' in o.name:
        o.hide_viewport = o.hide_render = False
```

Note that there are a few ways to hide objects. `object.hide_viewport` or `object.hide_render` or `object.hide_select`

You can find out stuff like that using autocomplete functionality of the Python console (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> while hovering mouse over Python console panel with some text you started typing):

[image]

`C` is short for `bpy.context` in the console. `C.object` is the active object.

Comment: Also working somehow but the icon in the outliner doesn't change... I think it is still unfinished or they forgot to remove the properies, I don't get it.

Comment: If I am not mistaken in some development builds it was removed and now it is back. I assumed this is in order to be more compatible with older scripts. There is nothing about it in the documentation, it's just there so I assume it is fine to use this as we always did. Maybe the new way is more efficient...