# How do I unhide all objects of a certain type?

Tags: python, scripting

I'm using blender 2.93 so not sure if that changes anything but i'm trying a simple script as [found here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/151257/how-to-unhide-hidden-objects-with-a-python-script)

```
import bpy

for o in ("Cube", "Camera", "Light"):
　　obj = bpy.context.scene.objects.get(o)
　　#if obj: obj.hide_viewport = False
　　if obj: obj.hide_set(False)
```

I have made a simple scene with cubes, point lights and cameras, some hidden, but if I run the script, nothing happens. It doesn't give any errors either so im not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm so stupid I guess. Any ideas?

Files here
[Script file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/y86p2mmgjzwj3yj/unhideall.py/file)
[Scene](https://www.mediafire.com/file/wmspbeh7al5q7eo/testscene.blend/file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function bpy.context.scene.objects.get() will get an object matching the name of the parameter passed to it, or return nothing if there isn't an object with that name. The line `for o in ("Cube", "Camera", "Light"):` iterates over the strings "Cube", "Camera", and "Light", which are the names of the default three objects when a new .blend file is created, so only those objects will get unhidden.

To iterate over all objects, use bpy.context.scene.objects as shown below:

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    obj.hide_set(False)
```

Comment: Ohh shoot, I thought the script I used was iterating over classes, not object names. Now I get it. (your script works perfectly). I'm coming from maxscript so its a little confusing, But how if I f.e. want to hide only all lights. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: `for obj in (o for o in bpy.context.scene.objects if o.type == 'LIGHT'):` Here are all the possible object types : https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.type (Make sure you use all caps)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thank you for that.